# Change Ubuntu server password every 7 days and do autologin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-scripting, unix-shell, ubuntu-22.04

am working on a scenario where i need to Change Ubuntu server password every 7 days and do autologin.

i tried with breaking the problem:
command to create user with password:

```
useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 "krspassword") krs
```

than using the `cron` to execute this every 7days

but didn't work

can some pls help.

Comment: Why don't you use key based logins?

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` command does not change the password, it *creates* a user and it fails if the user already exists. If you want to change the password of an existing user, use `usermod`:

```
usermod -p $(openssl passwd -1 "krspassword") krs
```

This will succeed only for *existing* users and fail for nonexisting.

For completeness, the "create or update" scriptlet might look like this:

```
PW=$(openssl passwd -1 "krspassword"); if ! usermod -p ${PW} krs > /dev/null 2>&1; then useradd -p ${PW} krs >/dev/null 2>&1; fi
```

It attempts to change the password and if there was no such user it creates it.

Notice that `-1` (MD5) encryption is obsolete. Better use `-5` (SHA256) or `-6` (SHA512).